# Stuck at splash-screen after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, plymouth

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. Everything went well until the reboot, and I'm currently stuck at splash-screen without having access to the login screen.
I own a asus 1015pn.

If I press esc during the splah-screen i get a lot of lines but the only "[Fail] ones" are:
- speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher landscape-client is not configured, please run landscape config
- starting configure display device for EeePC 1015PN
- starting load fallback graphics device

All the other lines are [OK].

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried booting into recovery mode? To do this: hold down shift during bootup, then you should see a menu pop up. Navigate to the menu item that looks somewhat like this. "Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.8.0-26-generic (recovery mode)" using the arrow keys, then press enter to boot into recovery mode.

Comment: Yes I've tried to run the failsafe mode but it's not working either...